# how to use Parent-child transitions with Material-ui on desktop

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, material-ui

I have a list in a drawer that is docked to the browser screen (desktop) and I want to expand the content of the list item to fill the entire drawer when I click on it just like explained in this [demo](https://material.io/design/assets/0B8wSqcLwbhFubWY5ZWNxNjJBVEE/hierarchicaltransitions-1-spec.mp4):

[image]

I could find ways of doing it using Android but not using react material-ui V1.0.

Has anyone already done something like it?

Comment: any ideas here?